# How to remove tomcat plugin from Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a maven project and its is incorporated with tomcat 7 plugin. Whenever I do maven:install its generating in war file and placing it is in tomcat web apps folder, And I can access using localhost:8080

Now I want to change tomcat7 to tomcat 8 And also want to run tomcat separately.

Now I am using Tomcat7 plugin with maven, I dont want to use Tomcat 7 along with maven, I want to use Tomcat 8 which is in my system.

How to do that?

For my new tomcat server is it possible to tell maven to place generated war files to new tomcat sever webapps folder.

PLease find my below pom.xml for tomcat plugin configuration

```
   <!-- Used by embedded Tomcat to move context.xml for JNDI resources -->
            <!-- Configuration inherited from parent -->            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Main configuration inherited from parent -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <port>${httpPort}</port>
                    <httpsPort>${httpsPort}</httpsPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And below is my ant script which will help to deploy war file in embedded tomcat

```
<target name="tomcat" >
        <delete dir="war/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <artifact:mvn mavenHome="${maven.home}" fork="true">
            <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=256M" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n" />
            <jvmarg value="-javaagent:${spring.instrument.path}" />
            <jvmarg value="-Druntime.environment=${runtime.environment}" />
            <jvmarg value="-Ddatabase.user=${database.user}" />  
            <jvmarg value="-Ddatabase.password=${database.password}" />  
            <jvmarg value="-Ddatabase.driver=${database.driver}" />  
            <jvmarg value="-Ddatabase.url=${database.url}" />  
            <arg value="compile"/>
            <arg value="war:exploded"/>
            <arg value="tomcat7:run"/>
        </artifact:mvn>
    </target>
```

And my Parent Pom.xml

```
            <!-- Moves the context.xml file into a location that embedded Tomcat can read from -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${tomcat.conf.dir.name}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>


    <directory>${project.basedir}/../lib/${tomcat.conf.dir.name}</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Main coniguration for embedded Tomcat -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
<!--                         Useful when deploying to Tomcat elsewhere on the system -->
                        <update>true</update>
                        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <username>tomcatscript</username>
                        <password>secret</password>


    <additionalConfigFilesDir>${project.build.directory}/${tomcat.conf.dir.name}</additionalConfigFilesDir>
<!--                         See the configuration in the keytool-maven-plugin -->
                        <keystorePass>broadleaf</keystorePass>
                        <keystoreFile>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/blc-example.keystore</keystoreFile>

<!--                         System properties for JNDI data sources (database.url, database.driver etc) are passed in via -->
<!--                             build.xml as -D arguments -->

                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
<!--                         Other dependencies -->

                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                            <version>7.0.30</version>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <scope>compile</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

Now How can I change my pom.xml or ant script to remove embedded tomcat and include local tomcat 
When I run my ant script Maven should be able to deploy or redeploy it to local tomcat installation.

Thanks

Comment: Well, there's a tomcat8 plugin ... but it's really not clear what you want when you say you "want to keep tomcat separately".

Comment: You should edit your question to include the relevant portion of the pom.xml file.

Comment: @Rob will provide you soon ..

Comment: @dcsohl I dont want to use tomcat 7 as plugin to maven, I want to use tomcat installation in my system

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the tomcat7-maven-plugin relevant configuration that starts Tomcat7.

Second, you can configure tomcat7-maven-plugin to use Tomcat X REST Management API and deploy your war to it by using maven as described http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/deploying-to-tomcat-7-with-maven/

Comment: That link explains how to use embedded tomcat maven plugin.. I want to remove tomcat plugin with maven and add tomcat local installation

Comment: No, the link explains how to use tomcat-maven-plugin in order to deploy to a local Tomcat installation. In order to do that, you just need to specify configuration options: `url`, `username` and `password`. Then, you run `mvn tomcat7:deploy`.

Comment: Note that when you use `tomcat7-maven-plugin` you're not always using embedded Tomcat7. You use the embedded one only if you use goal `run` or some others. Goals `deploy`, `undeploy` or `redeploy` do not use the embedded one. Nevertheless, it is true that `tomcat7-maven-plugin` depends on the embedded one, as such it will be downloaded to your maven local repo. However, it will not be used in case you execute goals I listed above.

Comment: Can you explain it in your Answer with more briefly .. Thank you !!